# How to get the physical size of android's screen programatically in java?

Tags: java, android

I am coding to find out the pieces of information of the display in android.
**Something I did to find out the screen height in pixels is:**

```
public static int getScreenHeight() {
return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;}
```

And it's working properly. But I also wanted to get the screen's ***physical width and height*** , how do I get this? is it possible?
**Thanks**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `DisplayMetrics` class includes all the information you need:

- `widthPixels`
- `xdpi`

And

- `heightPixels`
- `ydpi`

These second values correspond to the number of pixels per inch for the physical screen, so you can compute e.g. the width in inches like this:

```
float widthInches = metrics.widthPixels / metrics.xdpi;
```