Can I find real phone size by adb?
I want to find real phone size by adb
example : S24 Ultra - 70.6 X 147 X 7.6 (mm)
How can I do it...
I input adb shell wm size but it isn't the real size of the phone
adb shell wm size`
physical size : 1440x3120
Override size : 1080x2340


If you have those values and the xdpi/ydpi numbers you can at least calculate the physical size of the screen (which might be quite a bit smaller than the device): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66309613/how-to-get-the-physical-size-of-androids-screen-programatically-in-java and https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/44480/a-way-to-get-the-current-resolution-size-and-dpi-from-the-command-line-terminal

Using AndroidViewClient/culebra you can do something like this
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient

print(ViewClient.view_client_helper().device.display_physical_size())

and you can obtain (in this case using a Pixel 8 Pro)
{'physical_width': 2.76, 'physical_height': 6.14, 'screen': 6.73}

As this was an interesting use case I just added an example to the repo: screen-size
